# Adding legend to a margin of a multiple for loop plot

Tags: r, plot, legend

This is perhaps an old question, but I can't find a satisfactory answer anywhere. Say that I have a following code:

```
par(mfrow = c(2,1), mar = c(4,4,1,1), oma=c(2,2,2,2))
stuff <- c("ed", "bla")
cols <- c("red", "blue")
for(i in 1:length(stuff)) {
x <- rnorm(10,3,2)
y <- seq(1,10)
plot(x,y, type = "o", col = cols[i], xlab = paste("stuff about", stuff[i]))}
legend("bottomright", legend = stuff, col = cols, lwd = 1, bty = "n")
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
title(main = "ed & bla", outer = T)
mtext("This is a plot", 3, line=0.5, adj=1.0, cex=1, outer=TRUE)
```

How can I add the legend in the bottom margin of the plot?

[image]

Comment: Either use `layout()` or `par(mfrow=c(2,1))`. (See the examples in ?par.) `legend` should get plotted within the last plot

Comment: You can put the legend inside the loop, but only draw it if it is the last iteration: `if(i==length(stuff)){legend(...)}`.

Comment: Hadn't thought about that. Very helpful. Thanks Vincent!

Comment: This question is still active...How to place the legend in the margin under the plot?

Answer (score 3):

Re-order the plot requests, so that you plot the legend immediately after the last plot (outside the loop) but before the next modification to the plot parameters.  Note that only the "legend" command has been moved:

```
par(mfrow = c(2,1), mar = c(4,4,1,1), oma=c(2,2,2,2))
stuff <- c("ed", "bla")
cols <- c("red", "blue")
for(i in 1:length(stuff)) {
x <- rnorm(10,3,2)
y <- seq(1,10)
plot(x,y, type = "o", col = cols[i], xlab = paste("stuff about", stuff[i]))}
legend("bottomright", legend = stuff, col = cols, lwd = 1, bty = "n")
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
title(main = "ed & bla", outer = T)
mtext("This is a plot", 3, line=0.5, adj=1.0, cex=1, outer=TRUE)
```

This puts the legend into the bottom-right of the bottom plot.

Comment: Mhh..thanks! Any idea how to place the legend in the outer margin under the last plot?

Answer (score 0):

but you have to set the coordinate manualy

```
par(mfrow = c(2,1), mar = c(4,4,1,1), oma=c(2,2,2,2))
stuff <- c("ed", "bla")
cols <- c("red", "blue")
for(i in 1:length(stuff)) {
  x <- rnorm(10,3,2)
  y <- seq(1,10)
  plot(x,y, type = "o", col = cols[i], xlab = paste("stuff about", stuff[i]))}
legend(y=-5, x=5, legend = stuff, col = cols, lwd = 1, bty = "n", xpd=NA)
```